# Si uso ID en un input de type="submit" no funciona el formulario

Tags: php, html

tengo un problema, estoy intentando hacer que este formulario funcione con un submit que está fuera del form.

```
<button class="btn btn-success crop_image"><label for="submit-form">Recortar imágen</label></button>
```

Este boton solo funciona por el label que le he puesto.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server" autocomplete="off" id="myform">
      <input type="file" name="profile_photo" id="profile_photo" style="opacity: 0.0; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height:100%;margin-left: 10px;border-radius: 100%;cursor: pointer;">
      <input type="hidden" name="profile_photo">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-form">
</form>
```

Si le quito el id="submit-form" al hacer submit me devuelve el input file, pero con el id me lo da vacío. No lo entiendo, ayuda por favor.

Comment: Si cambias de nombre al `id` te sucede lo mismo? Arriba tienes en el `label for` el miso nombre.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Si quieres enviar el formulario desde un elemento que está fuera de él, asígnale un `id`  a ese elemento y en Javascript ponle un listener que escuche los clicks del mismo y desde allí recoge los datos del formulario y envíalos. En ese caso, el input de tipo submit no tendría sentido dentro del formulario porque por el motivo que sea has decidido que quien lo envíe sea otro elemento que está fuera.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando el ID del form "myform"

```
<button type="submit" form="myform" class="btn btn-success crop_image"><label for="submit-form"  >Recortar imágen</label></button>
```

Aunque creo que esto no funciona en edge